# Does Java Class Double Methods have any method for multiplication/ division /remainder?

Tags: java, class, double

Does Java Class Double Methods have any method for multiplication/ division /remainder?
I have found only for Sum?
static double   sum​(double a, double b)

For example I need to multiply 100.101101 and 110.101101

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [how `sum(double a, double b)` is implemented](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Double.java#L1143)?

While it would probably nice to have `prod()`, `div()` and `remainder()` too, you can easily implement them in a similar way for yourself:

```
public static double prod(double a, double b) {
    return a*b;
}
```

and similarly for the other two methods.